# Why "if an object has two bindings, and one goes away, the reference count does not go back to 1"?

Tags: r

*Advanced R* 2019 says about copy-on-modify for objects. Then some exceptions (modify-in-place):

> If an object has a single name bound to it, R will modify it in place.
>
> Two complications make predicting exactly when R applies this optimisation
>   challenging:
>
> - When it comes to bindings, **R can currently  only count 0, 1, or many**. That
>     means that **if an object has two bindings, and one goes away, the reference
>     count does not go back to 1: one less than many is still many**. In turn, this
>     means that **R will make copies when it sometimes doesn’t need to**.
> - ...

Are the following two sentences contradict each other?

- "R can currently  only count 0, 1, or many".
- "if an object has two bindings, and one goes away, the reference
  count does not go back to 1: one less than many is still many" and "R will make copies when it sometimes doesn’t need to".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this statement remains correct. Let's take a look with `.Internal(inspect())`.

Consider assigning as the following:

```
x <- 1L
x[[1]] <- 2L
x
#[1] 2
```

If we use `.Internal(inspect(x))`:

```
.Internal(inspect(x))
#@7fa684891478 13 INTSXP g0c1 [NAM(1)] (len=1, tl=0) 2
```

We see based on `[NAM(1)]` that there is only one symbol referring to the address `7fa684891478`.

Now let's assign `x` to `y`.

```
y <- x
.Internal(inspect(y))
#@7fa684891478 13 INTSXP g0c1 [NAM(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 2
.Internal(inspect(x))
#@7fa684891478 13 INTSXP g0c1 [NAM(2)] (len=1, tl=0) 2
```

We see that `y` and `x` share the same memory address and `[NAM()]` is up to 2.

Now let's assign `x` to `z`.

```
z <- x
.Internal(inspect(x))
#@7fa684891478 13 INTSXP g0c1 [NAM(3)] (len=1, tl=0) 2
```

Regardless, even if we remove symbols pointing to `7fa684891478`, `[NAM()]` never increments down.

```
rm(z)
.Internal(inspect(x))
#@7fa684891478 13 INTSXP g0c1 [NAM(3)] (len=1, tl=0) 2
```

```
R.Version()
#...
#$version.string
#[1] "R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Given that "R can currently only count 0, 1, or many", "if an object
>   has two bindings, and one goes away", why "the reference count does
>   not go back to 1: one less than many is still many"

The NAMED mechanism counts the number of variables from which an object is reachable and only the values 0,1,2 are allowed ("2" means "2 OR more").

> and "R will make copies when it sometimes doesn’t need to"?

If more values were were allowed or R used a proper reference counting such copies would not be needed.

Therefore, reference counts that go above 1 (helping to reduce copying) will probably be implemented sometime. https://developer.r-project.org/Refcnt.html